# undefined variables when importing another less file. LESS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less

When I load my Quote View, I'm getting unprocessed less text at the top. Stating a list of less variables undefined. However when I refresh the same page, the error goes away, and the styles work fine. I realize that SSPContainer.less is loaded after ReadOnlyWaybill.less (incorrect)when error, and on page refresh (working fine) is loaded before. so why is it behaving like that?
I'm using mvc bundling.

**layout view** - uses the layout bundle including SSPContainer.less

**QuoteView** - uses the quote bundle, including ReadOnlyWizard.less. but it is also inheriting the 'layout bundle files' as layout view is the master page of Quote View.

error - variable @line such and such is undefined in ReadOnlyWizardLess

- SSPContainer.less - this is the parent less file, and declares the variables.
  -ReadOnlyWizard.less - this imports 'SSPContainer.less' and uses its less variables.

??

Comment: Maybe you need to build your css files and reference those on your pages (you can even go as far as minifying).